# How do I map a protected collection in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have tried using the Reveal property in Fluent but I can't get it to compile with a collection. I want one of my collections in an entity to be protected and not accessible anywhere except in the entity itself. Is this possible? Thanks

Edit:

Here's the code I'm trying to use,

```
HasMany<Trip>(x => Reveal.Property<Trip>("_trips"));
```

I've also tried this code as well,

```
HasMany<Trip>(Reveal.Property<Organization>("_trips"));
```

Everytime my app runs, NHibernate says it can't map to "Property" or it throws an unknown exception.

Comment: Reveal should work with collections, care to show us how you're doing it?

Comment: How is your `Trip` model defined?

Comment: Dit you ever get an answer to the Nhibernate excetion on "Property", i am getting the same thing

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that Organization has a **IList**<Trip> the

`HasMany<Trip>(Reveal.Property<Organization>("_trips"));`

code should work.
Check that it's a property and that you have protected getters and setters (privates will not work, since NHibernate will want to proxy the collection for lazyloading).

Comment: As you say, I think the key is to make sure it's an IList, not a List.   

I'm just calling attention to that detail since I just read your answer and then proceeded to implement is as List<T>... maybe this comment will help someone else avoid that mistake.

Comment: a very late comment on this topic. But Do you know if Nhibernate is satisfied with field. Or do you need to use properties? I would prefer field in my current project

Comment: You can use fields. In FNH I think you need to change the .Access modifier and there should be an option for Field

Comment: Yes, there are many variations on this syntax that seem right but don't work. What fooled me, was the Reveal.Member<TYPE> is the owning class not the list type

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to allow the mapping of protected internal virtual properties.  This is document in the NHibernate Fluent [documentation](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties#use-internals).

1. Go to your **AssemblyInfo.cs** (under Properties) file and add the following: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyDomain.mapping")]` where the string is the namespace of the mapping.
2. create properties with the **protected internal virtual** access declarations.

   ```
       protected internal virtual IList<Clinician> __AppointmentMemberAttendees { get; set; }
   ```
3. Map items just like normal.

   ```
       HasManyToMany(x => x.__AppointmentMemberAttendees)
              .Table("__AppointmentToAttendeesMember")
              .Cascade.None();
   ```