# Fluent NHibernate Reveal not using given propertyname

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to map the following protected collection in my class:

```
public class AddressList
{
    protected readonly IList<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
}
```

With the following mapping:

```
HasMany<Address>(list => Reveal.Member<AddressList>("addresses"));
```

But I keep getting a NHibernate.MappingException

```
NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: 
(XmlDocument) > NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException 
: Could not find a getter for property '**Member**' in class
```

But as you can see in the Reveal.Member I am stating that the propertyname it should be looking for should be "addresses"

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129343/how-do-i-map-a-protected-collection-in-fluent-nhibernate) question, the user seems to have the same problem as me only it's an old question

I have also tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781443/private-collection-mapping-in-fluent-nhibernate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use lambdas together with `Reveal`

As you see in the exception message:

> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: 
>   (XmlDocument) > NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException 
>   : Could not find a getter for property '**Member**' in class

I tries to map to a field named `Member` as you use `list => Reveal.Member` instead of just `Reveal.Member`

Comment: OMFG thank you (i am a true idiot, is there a badge for that? :))